# Get calculated CSS properties for an Template in Backbone.View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

Is is possible to get an **rendered** template calculated CSS values **without** attaching it to **DOM**?

I'm interested in Backbone.View $el CSS values and a way to pre-calculate it's properties like width and height without attaching them to DOM.

**If that's not possible**,

What's the best way to calculate target values for rendered templates so they can be used with jQuery.animate?

For example an fade in / fade out function that will be part of that's View extended methods

Comment: Are you opposed to attaching it to the DOM for performance or aesthetic reasons?

Comment: I want to have an 'opening' or 'closing' animation done and I need to calculate the target values for the animation. For example if a model changes it's data I want to recalculate height / width of some elements and make an animation when re-rendering the View instead of sudden change in DOM.

Comment: Have you considered appending the element to the DOM with visibility set to hidden, measuring it and then removing it?

Comment: If it's hidden, it's still affects how the DOM is rendered. This solution is kind of wierd: render it, make it hidden, attach to dom, calculate current width/height, remove from DOM, set opacity to 0, set height to 0, attach to DOM again, animate height to target value,.. o.O I wouldn't call this a good solution ;-) Is there a way to get the calculated CSS for an Element without attaching it to DOM? Preasumable that the Viewport is set to default.

Comment: It's certainly not a *good* solution, but I don't know of any alternatives...

Comment: > If it's hidden, it's still affects how the DOM is rendered.


Correct - it'd need to be positioned absolutely or something.

Comment: When I've had to do things like this, I'll clone the container, move it offscreen, insert the child, measure, then delete the clone.

Comment: @steveax you still need to attach it first. I'm wondering if that's possible without putting things into DOM - or am I miss understanding your concept? How about an example?

Comment: @PatrickJankun, yes, it still needs to be in the DOM to get the dimensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best bet other than performing the arduous task of inserting the element hidden, taking the measurements, and then removing it, is by using:

```
window.getComputedStyle
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle)

Then setup the methods in your views to look like:

```
fadeIn : function (event) {
    var rootElement = this.$el.get(0);
    var cssStyles = window.getComputedStyle(rootElement, null);
    var rootElementHeight = cssStyles.getPropertyValue("height");
    var rootElementWidth = cssStyles.getPropertyValue("width");

    // perform fadeIn animation     
},

fadeOut : function (event) {
    var rootElement = this.$el.get(0);
    var cssStyles = window.getComputedStyle(rootElement, null);
    var rootElementHeight = cssStyles.getPropertyValue("height");
    var rootElementWidth = cssStyles.getPropertyValue("width");

    // perform fadeOut animation     
},
```

It's not ideal and the height and width returned are just a representation of the final CSS rules applied to that element.  So it's entirely possible the actual height and width would change when the element was actually rendered on the page.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is indeed a nice approach! Thanks.